# iOS ISOCountryCodes returns empty array

Tags: ios, locale, nslocale

I have the following code:

```
NSArray *_countryCodes = [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes];
NSMutableArray *names = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:_countryCodes.count];

[_countryCodes enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *code, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

    NSString *displayName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:code];
    if (displayName != nil) {

        names[idx] = displayName;

    }

}];
```

For less than 0.2% of my users `_countryCodes` seems to be empty (in fact I got debug message, that `names` are empty).

All affected devices are on iOS 10.1/10.2 and have `en_PH` locale.

Any ideas what might be the reason?

Comment: I checked your code I am not getting any empty array I got countries

Comment: Your code is OK , but that might be due to "Threading" , Sometimes in my apps i am also getting some of array or values as nil or blank